# Need to form a JSON response in the following way from the following resultset

Tags: java, json, loops, resultset

This could be simple but I am not able to figure it out.

This is the ResultSet I am receiving from the database.

```
Name        Method      Value
Website     Online      450
Website     Offline     500
Mobile      Online      100
Mobile      Offline     600
```

I need to send the response to the front end in the following JSON Format.

```
response: [
        {
          "Name" : "Website",
          "Online" : 450,
          "Offline" : 500
        },
        {
          "Name" : "Mobile",
          "Online" : 100,
          "Offline" : 600
        }
]
```

I need to form that JSON in a single loop, preferably while reading the ResultSet itself. What is the best way to achieve that.?
Thanks in Advance.!

P.S : The query is already a complex one, so cannot pivot the table - performance issues. The above ResultSet is a sample, there may be hundreds of records in the ResultSet

Update:
I am not sure how efficient the following solution is, but it works.!

```
 Map<String, Map<String, Object>> objectMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Map<String, Object>>();
 Map<String, Object> map;
  while(rs.next()){
     if(objectMap.containsKey(rs.getString("Name"))){
        map = objectMap.get(rs.getString("Name"));
        map.put(rs.getString("Method"), rs.getInt("Value"));
    }
    else {
      map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      map.put("Tag", 0);
      map.put("Plate", 0);
      map.put("Name", rs.getString("Name"));
      map.put(rs.getString("Method"), rs.getInt("Value"));
    }
    objectMap.put(rs.getString("Name"), map);
 }

return objectMap.values();
```

Comment: you can post your solution under "answers" and accept it by yourself.

Comment: @BenediktS.Vogler Did that.! Thank You.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> objectMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Map<String, Object>>();
Map<String, Object> map;
 while(rs.next()){
     if(objectMap.containsKey(rs.getString("Name"))){
        map = objectMap.get(rs.getString("Name"));
        map.put(rs.getString("Method"), rs.getInt("Value"));
    }
    else {
      map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      map.put("Tag", 0);
      map.put("Plate", 0);
      map.put("Name", rs.getString("Name"));
      map.put(rs.getString("Method"), rs.getInt("Value"));
    }
    objectMap.put(rs.getString("Name"), map);
 }

return objectMap.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what JSON library you want to use but...

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
for (Result result : results) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("Name", result.name);
    obj.put("Method", result.method);
    obj.put("Value", result.value);
    jarray.put(obj);
}
```

Not really sure if that's what your asking.

Comment: Thanks for the response.! But that's not what I was asking though.. I found a solution and have updated it.!